# Get CurrentTime from Video Tag in Samsung Smart Tv

Tags: html, html5-video, samsung-smart-tv

I've installed Samsung Smart TV SDK and I'm trying to get the current frame/time the video is playing.

The video is already running, and everything seems to work just fine, but when I try to get the current time, using  $('#video1')[0].currentTime, I'm just getting the value in seconds, without the milliseconds.

I'm developing a program where I need the milliseconds, but it seems impossible to get them using the SDK. What am I doing wrong? Any tips? Or it's a SDK limitation, and I'll never be able to get the current "REAL" time?

I found some solutions online, read a lot about the video tag in HTML 5, but the SDK documentation seem to lack a lot of information, and some are even wrong...

I followed this example: http://jsfiddle[dot]net/893aM/1/

Works just fine in any browser, but when I apply it to the Smart Tv, I just get the time in seconds, no luck with my precious milliseconds...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following links:

- [Using SEF Plugin](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00014/sef_plugin_using.html) and [SEF Plugin API](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00014/index.html)
- [SEF Plugin Player](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00014/sef_plugin_player.html)
- "[OnCurrentPlaybackTime](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00014/OnCurrentPlaybackTime.html)" event from the SEF Plugin Player.

EDIT:

```
Player.OnCurrentPlayTime = function (milliseconds) {
  // use 'milliseconds' parameter
}
```

Comment: My SEF Plugin is now working, but I can't find a way to get the time in milliseconds. Is it a good idea to create my own timer after the video has loaded?
For example, create a time in a OnBufferingComplete Event. That way I can keep track of the time, because OnCurrentPlaybackTime is an event and it doesn't seem to return me anything related with current Video Play time.

Comment: OnCurrentPlaybackTime() first parameter - current playback time in miliseconds

Answer (score 0):

or you can convert it by yourself

```
Player.OnCurrentPlayTime = function (time) {
  var hms = time.toString().split(":");
  var seconds=(parseInt(hms[0],10)*60*60+parseInt(hms[1],10)*60+parseInt(hms[2],10))*1000;
  alert(seconds);}
```